# iOS Drag and Drop on development

Tags: ios

i saw some vidoe where people are allowed to drag and drop buttons to develop their application, may i know how can i get it to work in my xcode or something? It works like VIsual studio form development etc. where u can drag eg a button and give it a name etc.

Regards,
TransformBinary

Comment: [Interface Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html)

Answer (score 3):

Apple provides a documentation resource for this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/EstablishingBindingsDragging.html

Comment: Hi just to check, i saw some videos and they chose windows application, i cant find the option. May i know if by paying the $99 and free xcode , is there a difference between the xcode? i'm developing a app, want to use the object library

Comment: there is no difference at all. even when you pay for the program, they link you to the free app store XCode version. The program fee is needed for testing on devices, deployment on the app store and additional resources

Comment: If you use OS X Lion you can download XCode 4.3.1 via the Mac App Store